# Reorder integers such that the biggest value is in the middle with decreasing values on either side

Tags: r

Is there a better way to reorder a vector of integers such that the biggest value is in the middle with decreasing values on either side of the biggest value. In the reordered vector, the value in the middle has to be the biggest. The next two big values have to go on left and right of the biggest value (whichever is fine) and so on.

```
#DATA
set.seed(42)
ints = sample(1:15, 51, replace = TRUE)

#CURRENT SOLUTION
ints2 = sort(ints, decreasing = TRUE)
left = c()
right = c()
for (i in seq_along(ints)){
    if (i %% 2 == 0){
        right = c(right, ints2[i])
    } else {
        left = c(left, ints2[i])
    }
}
ints2 = c(rev(left), right) #DESIRED OUTPUT

#Check if ints and ints2 have the same values
identical(sort(ints), sort(ints2))
#[1] TRUE
```

For further clarification, here is a plot of the initial data in red and reordered data in blue.

```
#Initial Data
plot(x = seq_along(ints), y = ints, col = "red", type = "l", xlab = "index", ylab = "value")

#Re-ordered Data
lines(x = seq_along(ints2), y = ints2, col = "blue")
```

Comment: Maybe something like this `c(sort(ints)[seq_along(ints) %% 2 == 0],sort(ints,decreasing = T)[seq_along(ints) %% 2 == length(ints) %% 2])` sort, take half, sort decreasingly, take half and combine? You could also sort once and store it, take half and `rev` the other half and combine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
i <- seq_along(ints)
r <- rank(-abs(i - median(i)), ties.method = "random")
sort(ints)[r]
```

Explanation: `abs(i - median(i))` gets a sequence for each item of its distance from the center, and `rank` turns them into indices, with the center (the lowest distance) getting the highest value (51). `sort(ints)[r]` then puts the last value there, the next highest adjacent to it, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with matrix manipulation:

```
x <- sort(ints)
if(length(x) %% 2 == 1){
    x <- c(x, NA)
}

m <- matrix(x, ncol = 2, byrow = T)
m[, 2] <- rev(m[, 2])
m[!is.na(m)]
```